# I am available every day until 1pm

Tags: difference, usage, adverbs, time

Is this sentence grammar correct?

> I am available every day until 1pm and all day weekends.

I am not sure *every day* or *everyday* and I think I need to write *weekday* instead of *every day*

Comment: If you're not sure about *every day* vs *everyday*, did you try doing a search like [this one](http://www.google.com/search?rls=en&q=every+day+vs+everyday&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)?

Comment: The simplest "fix" is *I am available Monday through Friday until 1pm and all day weekends.* If you switch it to work days, well not every works the same days you. ;)

Answer (score 4):

Where's the preposition in the latter half of the sentence?

> I'm available every day until 1 pm, and all day **during/on** weekends.

But...

> On weekdays, I'm available till 1 pm; on weekends, I'm available all day *(or any time)*.

seems a better, simpler sentence without any ambiguity.

['everyday' is an adjective **and** 'every day' functions as an adverb.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6644/what-is-the-difference-between-everyday-and-every-day) It's good to learn the difference. So here, you don't use it as an adjective. In other words, it's 'every day' and not 'everyday'.

As I said, when you want to show a contrast to weekends, 'weekdays' or 'working days' is preferable **over** every day.

Comment: +1 I took the liberty of fixing minor typos. It was so tempting for me to edit *is preferable **over*** to *preferable **to*** because I would always use *to*, but then I thought *preferable over* might be possible in Indian English. (This could be useful: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1752/which-is-correct-prefer-x-to-y-or-prefer-x-over-y, http://talk.collegeconfidential.com/sat-preparation/1073547-preferable-over-idiom.html.)

Comment: @DamkerngT. I use *over* when two choices are given **clearly** as in my answer. On the other hand, I use *to* if it's not **clearly** given - "I have a bike, but I prefer *to* walk for short distances."